# How to trigger block IP in Cloudflare when Firewall block event is triggered?

Tags: firewall, cloudflare

I want to create a Firewall rule that triggers IP block action when Firewall event action is equal to "block".

Current Cloudflare GUI does not have the rule.

How can I create  the rule using the expression builder?